# Run Yii application into a frame without changing url

Tags: wordpress, yii

Can I run a Yii application into a frame without changing URL. (Run on single page)

I am trying to run Yii application into a frame on WordPress theme-template, application working but appl. menu access changed its url, then wp theme dint load in application.

Have a look:
[Snap-1][1]
[snap-2][2]

Plz someone give suggestion to do it in right way.

Comment: You could try parsing the requests with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to run Yii inside of WordPress, you're probably better off just replicating your design within Yii, and running WordPress and Yii simultaneously.

Of course, that's going to be a nightmare to maintain, so the best solution would be ditching WordPress or Yii and try to bring all the required functionality under one application roof.

Comment: I agree with you Mr. Chris Fletcher, but my application is wordpress theme specific, i cant implement wp-theme in yii. My purpose to design application in yii on a single-page, and page will used as template into any of wordpress-theme.
If it's done, then all thing done. (is am thinking right??? or it's possible by another way???)